# Load more pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am having issue with my PHP MySQL JavaScript load more pagination issue

Here's my PHP MySQL HTML codes

```
<div class="postList">
    <?php
        $page = 1;
        if(isset($_POST['page'])) {
            $page = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
            if(false === $page) {
                $page = 1;
            }
        }

        // set the number of items to display per page
        $items_per_page = 5;

        // build query
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
        $sql = "SELECT id,title,size,time,category,hash FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $postID = $row['id'];
    ?>
    <div class="list_item"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main<?php echo $postID; ?>">
        <span id="<?php echo $postID; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more data">Show more</span>
        <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'index.php',
            data:'id='+ID +'&page='+<?php echo $offset;?>,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.postList').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I am able to get the first 5 records on screen by default and when I press load more button it gives me the same first 5 records again and when I press load more button the 2nd time its keep giving me the same first 5 records repeatedly like a multi loop.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not passing a `PAGE` get value on your javascript call, that's why it's always 1, so you need to pass that variable on your javascript `data`...also the javascript call should be a `GET` call.

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman actually I grab this pagination codes from other script which was using `GET` method but in the code above i want `POST` method is it possible to achieve this using 'POST` method?

Comment: It is possible. But usually pagination requests are posted via `GET`.

Comment: I know that, but project I am working on it required to use `POST` method and I don't want to call the number of pages in the `URL` on browser.

Comment: You can use post, you just need to change this line `if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {` and make it a `$_POST` var...also you should use an `isset` check.

Comment: I have changed it to `if(isset ($_POST['page'])) {` but results are still the same

Comment: Yeah, but you are missing the step, where `data:'id='+ID,` should be something like `data:'id='+ID +'&PAGE='+2,`

Comment: I have updated my question according your solution but still the same.

Comment: Can you add an `echo $sql;` to your script in order to check the query?